# ¿Cómo hago para rescatar palabras separadas en la base de datos usando ajax+php?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy rescatando datos de mi base de datos con ajax y php, y resulta que las palabras separadas como "crema catalana" solo me coge "crema" y no sé a qué se debe esto. Si alguien sabe el motivo que lo comparta con los demás.

```
$("#helados").click(function() {  // con esto mostramos las categorias.
    var helados="helados";
    $("#productostpv").empty();
    $.get("./php/getProductos.php?categoria="+helados, function(data, status){
            if (status=="success"){
                data=JSON.parse(data);
                for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    $("#productostpv").append("<input type=button class=inputzz onclick=llenarLista(this.id) id="+data[i].idproducto+" value="+data[i].descripcionn+">");
                }
            }
});
});
```

Comment: El problema según veo esta en la comparación de tu for, debería ser `for (i=0;i <= data.length;i++)` Menor o igual

Comment: Quizá no sea la mejor manera de parsear tu JSON. Si pones un breve ejemplo de cómo vienen los datos en el JSON y de cómo quieres presentarlos, entonces podríamos sugerirte una mejor manera de leer y presentar los datos.